# Поздравляем Harry с достижением 100 000 баллов репутации!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

От лица сообщества, поздравляю [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) с достижением 100 000 баллов репутации на Stack Overflow на русском! 100 000 — это серьезный рубеж, до которого сегодня удалось добраться лишь нескольким участникам.  Большое спасибо вам за помощь коллегам! Уверен, каждый из почти трех тысяч ваших ответов помог не одному десятку разработчиков.

С нетерпением ждем еще больше интересных ответов от вас на сайте!

[image: Учетная запись Harry]

Коллеги, пожалуйста, присоединяйтесь к поздравлениям!

Comment: Поздравляем! Ура!

Comment: Поздравляю! В ответах Harry есть, чему поучиться, да и просто читать интересно :)

Comment: @Harry: Примите поздравления со стороны _нескольких участников_!

Comment: @Harry, Поздравляю с замечательным результатом! Так держать, не останавливайтесь на достигнутом!

Comment: Поздравляю! Harry внес значительный вклад в развитие сайта, желаю ему первого места )

Comment: Поздравляю @Harry!!!!

Comment: а миллионеры по репутации (на eng SO) существуют? )

Comment: @xhr Чак Норрис дотнета - Джон Скит

Comment: @xhr https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all  Пока один.

Comment: @byVerng Спасибо - не знал, что можно чарты пользователей смотреть ) Лично мне до 1М надо умножить свою репу всего-то на 6k раз )))

Comment: На большом Stack Overflow [за 100K-get выдают призы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation/). Практикуется ли подобное у нас? Если нет, то почему нет, если да, то можно поподробнее рассказать про призы?

Comment: @defaultlocale Да, на сколько я могу помнить. Эта инициатива для всех сайтов сети Stack Exchange. Про призы — это секрет! =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky А очень зря, это бы намного больше мотивировало, если бы это было не секретом. В отличие от виртуальных значков, это очень приятный материальный приз. Помимо этого есть ощущение настоящего признания от компании, а не "сухих" автоматически присуждаемых значков.

Comment: Мои поздравления!

Comment: Добро пожаловать в клуб!

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, вот Harry получит и выложит фото)))

Comment: Ещё один рейд-босс. Помню, как на первого пати собирали... Теперь два штуки стало (c).

Comment: а на stackoverflow есть рейтинг пользователь по репутации?

Comment: @Анатолий выше давал ссылку.... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

Comment: @by Verng спасибо, не увидел сразу

Comment: Во дела-у нас всего 2 человека за 100к репутации. открыл английскую версию-19 страниц. И есть даже миллионик

Comment: @Анатолий это очевидно, там людей в разы больше, поэтому плюсов и вопросов в разы больше.

Comment: @by Verng надо и нам поднажать

Comment: От всей души поздравляю! Пару раз помогал мне, очень качественные ответы :)

Answer (score 79):

[*Растроганно утирая слезы*] Всем огромное спасибо!

Ушел отмечать :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Поздравляю Вас с ярким, долгожданным и конечно заслуженным событием!!! А какие были у Вас  ощущения, эмоции, когда достигли этой вершины? Ведь это совсем не просто. Мотивация идти дальше вперёд не пропала?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Скажу прямо - эмоций особо никаких. Например, золото за тэг "алгоритмы" или серебро за "математику" вызвало эмоций куда больше. О мотивации... главная мотивация - это когда интересно :) Мне просто интересно общаться - в силу специфики работы, реального общения у меня очень немного, а здесь и общение, и на интересные темы. Не скажу, что баллы совсем не интересуют - это было бы преувеличением :), но все же это далеко не самое главное...

Comment: Поздравляю вас с этим великим днем и еще скоро 8 марта

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат Поверьте, я таки мужчина, меня с 8 марта поздравлять не нужно :)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям !!!