# C Новым 2020 Годом!

Tags: поддержка, итоги-года

Уходящий год был насыщенным и довольно непростым как для сообщества, так и для компании. Мне лично запомнились следующие позитивные события нашей общей истории:

- В этом году команда модераторов [пополнилась](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9229/6) двумя участниками [Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/) и [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/).
- Репутация [Harry](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8833/) в сообществе превысила порог в 100 000 баллов.
- [Размер создаваемой нами базы знаний перевалил за четверть миллиона вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8572/6)!
- В этом году мы вместе успешно завершили несколько невероятно важных инициатив. Например, добавили в справочный центр «[ключевые ценности](/help/key-values)» и «[манифест сообщества](/help/manifesto)».

Уху! Так держать!

#### Год в цифрах

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | на русском         |  на русском       |
|                    | 2018 год           |  2019 год         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Задано вопросов   |     86 573         |    77 986         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|Опубликовано ответов|     70 969         |    56 949         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Новых участников  |     39 557         |    41 189         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Несколько мыслей о будущем

- *Особое внимание отзывам участников*. Как я могу видеть, [компания взяла уверенный курс](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) на улучшения опыта участия на сайте. И, что очень важно, вводить улучшения планируется на основе отзывов участников сообщества. Хотя мы опирались на ваши идеи при принятии решений с самого первого дня, с этого года возможности поделиться своими мыслями о сайте будет ещё больше. Если вы хотели изменить что–либо на сайте, настало отличное время осуществить ваши планы!
- *Видеочаты, встречи сообщества, конкурсы* и другие инициативы для «создания сообщества». Было бы здорово в новом году проводить больше подобных событий.
- *Концентрация на миссии проекта*. Если мы сможем максимально эффективно избегать всего (и хорошего, и плохого), что пытается сместить фокус нашего внимания с миссии, создания базы знаний сообщества, сайт будет развиваться быстрее и принимать участие будет ещё приятнее. Один из способов — выбрать амбициозную цель и вместе сделать всё возможное для её достижения.

За последние 10 лет ИТ-мир изменился до неузнаваемости: ещё в 2010 году нужно было несколько дней разбираться как собрать «Hello World проект» под первые версии ОС Андроид, сегодня же приложение для машины для проигрывания музыки из соц сетей пишутся на JavaScript за несколько часов. Изменилось и само сообщество. Во всём. И мне крайне приятно осознавать, что вот уже почти 10 лет мы с вами вместе являемся катализатором этих, безусловно, позитивных изменений. Большое спасибо нам всем за это! =)

#### Stack Overflow — это мы! Давайте поздравим друг друга!

Присоединяйтесь к поздравлениям! Пожалуйста, поделитесь наиболее приятными позитивными событиями из жизни сообщества, которые запомнились именно вам. Если в уходящем году кто–то из участников сделал вашу жизнь лучше, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь поздравить его, сказать ему «спасибо» в ответе к этому вопросу. Уверен, этот участник будет очень рад вашему вниманию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Большое спасибо всем участникам сообщества [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)! Поздравляю с наступающим Новым Годом и желаю всего наилучшего! Буду рад видеть всех в Новом Году! Нас ждёт много всего интересного! =)*

Comment: И вас с Наступающим Новым годом! Старый год был трудный, но очень интересный благодаря нашему сайту. Не хочется произносить стандартных пожеланий, так что пусть сбудется всё или хотя бы половина того, что в ваших самых смелых мечтах

Comment: С Наступающим Новым Годом! ❄️☃️
Спасибо всей команде сайта SO за всё хорошее что было сделано!
Отдельное спасибо @NicolasChabanovsky за классный совместный видеочат, это было очень круто!

Comment: Было бы интересно еще сколько репы было заработано всеми суммарно. :)

Comment: А «ключевые ценности» и «манифест сообщества», спущенные сверху без всякого участия сообщества, — это тоже достижения? о_О

Comment: Статистика, кстати, удручающая. Несмотря на большее количество новых участников, количество вопросов упало на 10%, а ответов на 20%.

Comment: С Наступающим Новым Годом!!! ) Всем счастья и улыбок, невероятных вопросов и новых, неординарных ответов )

Comment: Несмотря на статистику этот год показался наиболее спокойным в сравнении с предыдущими! Да и статистика такая может быть потому что люди все больше разбираются сами и хватает той базы знаний что уже есть!))) Всех С Новым Годом! Пусть он будет продуктивным и успешным!

Comment: Присоединяюсь. С новым годом!

Comment: А планирует ли компания брать курс на соблюдение законов и лицензий? Моё письмо на legal@ было успешно проигнорировано, например.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! Всех с прошедшими праздниками!

Answer (score 23):

Поздравляю всех с [грядущим упразднением Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339051/will-meta-stack-exchange-be-removed-now) и [заменой её на анонимные опросники](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), когда мнение горстки завсегдатаев, которые по принципу Парето в основном наполняют сайт, будет значить ещё меньше.

Поздравляю с [уходом 50 модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) и 500 модераторскими подписями под [письмом, высказывающим огорчение](https://dearstackexchange.com/), которое осталось без ответа.

Поздравляю с [первыми постами](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) с [2000 минусов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) на Meta Stack Exchange, ставящими новую веху в разочаровании сообщества в компании Stack Overflow и действиях её руководства.

Поздравляю со [сбором $25000 на судебные разборки](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) с компанией Stack Overflow из-за дискредитации участника в прессе, результаты которых мы никогда не узнаем, а остатки собранного уйдут на благотворительность.

Поздравляю со [сменой лицензии контента](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0) без [подтверждения владельца контента](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333678/was-the-retroactive-change-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-approved-by-stack-exchanges-lawyers), что ставит ещё больше вопросов по легальному использованию контента на сайтах.

Поздравляю с [обесцениванием репутации](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) как хотя бы отдалённой меры опыта и знаний, потому что задавать вопросы нынче столь же ценно, как и отвечать на них.

Поздравляю с [анимированной рекламой на страницах](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network) и добавлением [слежки по цифровым отпечаткам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331960/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio).

Поздравляю с введением американо-центричных политик политической корректности, из-за которых [меньшинства чувствуют себя ещё более уязвлёнными](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339148/focusing-on-race-gender-and-sexuality-makes-minorities-feel-exposed-and-unwelco).

Поздравляю с [обрушением статистики на локальных сайтах Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336925/all-localized-stack-overflows-seem-to-suffer-from-a-decline-to-some-degree-why).

Это был трудный год. Не все проблемы, через которые прошло всемирное сообщество сети Stack Exchange, напрямую влияют на повседневную жизнь на локальном Stack Overflow на русском. Однако всё это — вестники изменений, которые грозят всем. Или, если посмотреть с другой стороны — отголоски изменений, которые здесь уже произошли.

Сайт на месте, большинство продолжает им пользоваться как ни в чём не бывало, и в этом плане вряд ли что-то поменяется. Поменялось отношение. Завяли последние ростки надежды. Посеяна горечь разочарования.

Мы всё переживём. Но 2019-й год ничто не отменит.

Всего плохого.

Comment: Этот_год_был_последним.jpg

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5P6ADakiwcg

Comment: @AK Изменение смысла и стиля ответа никогда не приветствовалось, особенно на Мете.

Comment: Извините, но не стоит откатывать правки явно улучшающие пост. В случае повторного отката буду вынужден зафиксировать попытку войны правок и требовать её остановки. Вы же не будете оспаривать, что моя правка значительно улучшает исходное сообщение? Ваш ответ остался вашим, редакция номер один. Это ваше авторское сообщение, но насколько я помню все всегда пользовались возможностью улучшить сообщение: и запятые-тире и вырезали англицизмы. Насколько я помню последние обсуждения: любые улучшения постов приветствуются, а вот войны правок -- нет.

Comment: @AK Вы изменили смысл, изменили стиль, добавили своё мнение, но ничего из вышеперечисленного не улучшает текст. "Явным улучшением" может считаться исправление ошибок (их в исходном тексте нет), улучшение форматирования (исходный ответ отформатирован верно) и т.п. Вы же изменили текст в соответствии с собственными предпочтениями, а не правилами русского языка. Это [не приветствуется](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200172). Вы заставляете меня ставить подпись под текстом, который я не писал. Кроме того, вы внесли семантические и синтаксические ошибки, то есть испортили ответ. Это вандализм.

Comment: @AK Войну правок, кстати, спровоцировали исключительно вы. Вы увидели, что автор не одобрил правку, однако повторно применили своё изменение без предварительного обсуждения. Странно обвинять в войне правок меня и угрожать мне применить блокировку к ответу, в то время как вы и спровоцировали откат стилистической правкой, и инициировали войну правок повторным применением неодобренной правки.

Comment: @AK, не знаю, как он, а я - буду.

Comment: Лично я вижу в этом посте только одну фразу, которая заслуживает редактирования – последнее "всего плохого". Все остальное – не вижу почему должно быть удалено или отредактировано.

Comment: @anton Последняя фраза - не случайна, это отсылка к BadComedian, который специализируется на подробной критике плохих фильмов с хорошей рекламой.

Comment: CoC: "Никаких резких замечаний или _враждебно настроенных фраз_. Какими бы ни были ваши намерения, подобное поведение может _негативно_ отразиться на ваших коллегах." --> **невежливый или оскорбительный**

Comment: @AntonMenshov, а вдруг и правда, заслужили...

Comment: @Victor: А где тут _резкое замечание_ или _враждебно настроенная фраза_?

Comment: @VladD И то, и то.

Comment: @Victor: А где именно? Я что-то не нахожу.

Comment: @VladD <q>Всего плохого.</q>

Comment: @VladD Да и все остальное тоже.

Comment: @Victor: Я не вижу, где в этой фразе _резкость_. Учитывая, что это цитата, нет тут и враждебного настроя. А где ещё?

Comment: @VladD Не все знают, что это цитата. Для цитат есть >.
А остальное — поздравление с плохими событиями. И еще вот это:<q>Поменялось отношение. Завяли последние ростки надежды. Посеяна горечь разочарования.</q>

Comment: @VladD CoC:"Какими бы ни были **ваши намерения**, подобное поведение может _**негативно** отразиться на ваших коллегах_.

Comment: @Victor: По факту это цитата. Не после каждой шутки нужно писать «лопата», и не перед каждой цитатой нужно писать `>`. А «завяли ростки надежды» — это резкость? Или отсутствие враждебного настроя должно проявляться в том, что нужно лгать? Ростки надежды, да, завяли.

Comment: @Victor: Приведите, пожалуйста, полную цитату. Вырванная из контекста цитата не объясняет ничего.

Comment: @VladD У кого как(по поводу ростков). А цитата без > или "" это еще и плагиат.

Comment: @Victor: А то, что правда может негативно отразиться на тех, кто носит розовые очки, известный факт. Ну я из-за этого не собираюсь переключаться на враньё.

Comment: @VladD Это — **открытое пожелание всего плохого**. Еще и на Новый Год.

Comment: @Victor: Если это плагиат, пусть Bad Comedian подаёт на этот ответ в суд. Если то, что вы говорите, правда, суд разберётся. :-P

Comment: @VladD Дело здесь не в плагиате, а в (на мой взгляд) оскорблении всего сообщества.

Comment: @Victor: Мы начинаем ходить кругами. Просто примите тот факт, что не все должны писать как вам нравится.

Comment: @Victor: Сообщество так оскорбилось, что поставило 26 плюсов и только 6 минусов. Странно, правда?

Comment: @VladD Но все должны писать в соответствии c CoC. И на русском ("ході").

Comment: @VladD Очень странно, что это еще модераторы не удалили.

Comment: @VladD Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103093/discussion-between-victor-says-reinstate-monica-and-vladd).

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, если вам так не нравится "все плохого" - довольно странная идея оборачивать его в цитату - так чтобы оно прям выделялось в тексте, чтобы уж точно все прочитали, что им желают плохого)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica вы подобными правками каждый раз этот вопрос проталкиваете на главную, что ещё больше привлекает к нему внимание (: И да, прошу перестать эту правку вносить. Уже всё обсудили и решили оставить сообщение в оригинальном виде.

Answer (score 11):

### Поздравляю всех, всех, всех с наступающим Новым 2020 годом!

В прошлом году, также под Новый 2019 год была интересная тема рассказывать о людях, с которыми познакомились в прошедшем году, чьи работы были интересны и полезны лично для ТС. Хочу поддержать традицию и немного написать о людях, которые приятно поразили меня в уходящем 2019 году.

**Кому интересна эта тема, расскажите о своих коллегах, может дополните ссылками  их работ.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не смотрите на его стаж в профиле, это была спящая учетная запись.
 Stranger активно начал действовать только в этом году и набрал рекордное количество репы **40к** за год!

Но запомнился он прежде всего своими яркими, оригинальными ответами. Общее количество, опять же за год перевалило за `1100`
 Я уверен,  многие помнят его  [первую оригинальную  работу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/927012/28748) на Новогоднем конкурсе 2019 года.
 С ним хорошо рядом отвечать в топике, на его бренд-имя люди летят как бабочки на огонь, но плохо участвовать с ним в одном конкурсе, так как победить его практически невозможно :=)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я до сих пор жалею, что Павел очень редко появляется и отвечает. Всего 47 ответов. Но посмотрите, какие они яркие и полезные.  [Как создать эффект Воды?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/825600/28748)

Павел ушёл, но обещал вернуться. Буду ждать его возвращения с нетерпением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Та же история, как с Павлом. Ярко блистал ответами и бросил активную деятельность.

Вот один из них: [Как сделать баннер с капающим краном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924052/28748)

Очень надеюсь, что Юра вернется!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы вместе с ним и @Air начали продвигать SVG на ruSO. Открыли [Svg_chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat), активно общались и попутно изучали SVG.

Вот одна из его работ:  [Стилизация и анимация текста SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803801/28748)

А это одна, из самых первых его работ: [Как нарисовать автомобиль с помощью команд SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787491/28748)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наша боевая подруга по SVG. Сколько всего было, сколько пройдено.
У этой девушки, как вопросы, так и ответы хороши. Она постоянно, что-то новое изучает, внедряет. Всегда с интересом читаю её вопросы и если могу, то отвечаю на них, но не всегда получается, вот такие заковыристые вопросы она задаёт!  :=)

[Посмотрите её ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926581/28748) на прошлогоднем конкурсе НГ и этим всё сказано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его ответы в основном в разделе Javascript. Кто отвечает в этом разделе, как правило, думают, что все хорошо знают JS и поэтому размещают, как минимум или наблюдается полное отсутствие поясняющих комментарий к ответам.

Ответы @OPTIMUS PRIME, буквально с самых первых постов, пребывания на сайте, приятно удивляли своей основательностью и стремлением донести в подробных пояснениях все нюансы. Бывало, его нещадно критиковали `опытные` участники за столь подробные объяснения и да, он к сожалению стал меньше комментировать в своих крайних ответах. Могу по дружески посоветовать, - делайте, как Вы сами считаете, правильней и лучше!

Comment: Спасибо, очень приятно!!! Но не стоило, в этом году моя активность в сообществе была минимальной! Спасибо что ты есть на ruSO и за все что делаешь для сообщества!!! С Новым Годом!

Comment: @HamSter ну тогда за старые заслуги и авансом, год только начинается

Answer (score 10):

Поздравляю нашу  команду модераторов!

@A K♦, @Nick Volynkin♦, @Nofate♦, @Qwertiy♦, @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica♦, @ЮрийСПб♦

Их труд для многих из нас был незаметен. Даже меньше виден чем вершина айсберга в океане
 Но благодаря им  очень быстро решались текущие вопросы. Благодаря их неустанной работе было комфортно и удобно работать на сайте.
 Часто посещали мысли, зачем люди совершенно бесплатно, без каких-либо материальных бонусов отдают столько времени для поддержания нормальной работы сайта.

Честно признаюсь, я так бы не смог и поэтому восхищаюсь их долготерпению, трудолюбию, мастерству и знаниям.
Видно даже со стороны, что труд модератора очень не лёгок.
Отрицательных эмоций, как мне кажется, хватает от всех разборок. И при этом наши модераторы остаются максимально корректны и вежливы. Просто железные люди!

Желаю всем модератором и всем коллегам, с которыми знаком и с теми, с кем ещё предстоит познакомиться по общим интересам  в наступающем Новом году, так держать, как держали руль в этом году! Успехов здесь и в офлайне. Более спокойного, более везучего и радостного года, чем был этот уходящий старый год!

Comment: Не наша команда больше? (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica наша, наша команда модераторов :) Убрал, чтобы не раздражало некоторых. Просто смотрю по предыдущему сообщению, людей которые уже год не работают на сайте и с плохим поздравляют. Вызвало ассоциацию, когда наш общий дом горит, а вместо воды заливают ведрами с бензином И что самое интересное плюсуют отчаянно :)

Comment: Меня тоже удивило, что заплюсовали лютую чернуху, которая к тому же не имеет отношения к реальным проблемам сайта. Если вспоминать плохое, можно было бы упоминуть, что "эксперимент" по отключению причины закрытия домашки завис в непонятно каком состоянии, или что сервис локализации до сих пор заблокирован РосКомНадзором. Вместо этого стонем по поводу изменения версии лицензии, условия которой большинство и не читало...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Горькая правда лучше сладкой лжи.

Comment: @Kyubey какая сладкая ложь? Я хотел искренне поздравить людей, с кем работаю, кто мне дорог.  Вот лично мне, вы капитально испортили своим топиком предновогоднее настроение, как и многим  другим. Нашли же время и место, ни раньше, ни позже Почему нельзя было опубликовать сей топик в другом месте на Мете, пока её не закрыли и бороться там. Я прошу ВАС, удалите или перенесите свой пост  в более подходящее место.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Часть перечисленных вами модераторов неактивна, один модератор совсем недавно ушёл с поста. Мнение Николаса по "The Loop" и другим вопросам идёт вразрез с восприятием изменений сообществом. Мой ответ, может, и мерзкий, но искренний. Для кого-то это важно. ¶ Я не верю в даты, праздники, поздравления и прочую символику. Для праздничного настроения нужна не дата, а радостные события. В последнее время их было мало.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight по эксперименту я получил кое-какие данные от Шога. Через пару дней пост напишу про это.

Answer (score 8):

Поздравляю всё сообщество с Новым годом! Я совсем недавно стал заниматься программированием (хотя у меня и есть диплом по ВТ), во время обучения меня всё это не интересовало - нужен был диплом. А теперь в силу некоторых обстоятельств, программирование стало не только моей основной работой, но и хобби. И ***.stackoverflow.com** стал частью моей жизни. Благодаря сообществу я смог решать поставленные мне задачи и помогать другим членам сообщества (что мне очень нравится).

Отдельно хочу выделить [Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q) - так держать! Что не ответ то шедевр!

Answer (score 8):

## Поздравляю с Новым 2020 годом и Рождеством!

Дорогие друзья!

Сердечно поздравляю всех с Новым годом и Рождеством! Пусть 2020 год станет годом новых свершений и дальнейшей плодотворной работы. Пусть он запомнится яркими вопросами, интересными ответами и успехами в любых проектах. Пусть обязательно сбудется всё то, что в волшебную новогоднюю ночь Вы загадали! Искренне желаю Вам в наступившем году крепкого здоровья, безграничного счастья и благополучия!

**Дорогие друзья, с Рождеством, с Новым 2020 Годом!**

[image: Дорогие друзья, с Рождеством, с Новым 2020 Годом!]

Хочется сказать пару слов благодарности! Спасибо тем, кто задавал вопросы, на которые у меня была возможность ответить и мои ответы оказались полезными. Спасибо всем, кто отвечал на мои вопросы и таким образом помог мне реализовать интересные проекты. Отдельную благодарность хотелось бы выразить следующим участникам сообщества:

**@Air

@рони

@Cheg

@Kirill

@Grundy

@Qwertiy

@HamSter

@Дмытрык

@Alexandr_TT

@Алексей Шиманский

и многие другие...**

* *имена указаны в случайном порядке*

Каждый из Вас в свое время помог мне реализовать исключительно важные для меня проекты!

Я хочу сказать спасибо,
Вы мне очень помогли!
Пусть добро добром вернется,
Пусть нагрянет счастье к Вам,
Пусть все в жизни удается,
Выражаю благодарность нынче Вам!

С уважением, **@Sevastopol'**