# Когда вернут причину закрытия "учебные задания"?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, домашки

Когда вернут причину закрытия "учебные задания"?

Comment: Надеюсь, никогда.

Comment: @avp Зря. Все равно такие вопросы будут закрывать, минусовать, удалять. Просто по другим причинам.

Comment: Плохо. Наверное из-за такого подхода к нам и отношение соответствующее -- лучше на ruSO с вопросами не соваться...

Comment: @avp Вот интересно у кого такое отношение ?

Comment: У десятков людей. По крайней мере мне **никого из коллег** не удалось убедить пойти сюда и задать вопрос.

Comment: @avp Может быть ваши коллеги просили решать за них задачу? (думаю вряд ли). И еще здесь: 17k человек (хотя не все активно участвуют в жизни сообщества).

Comment: Ну, у всех тут разные цели. Я, например, сейчас в основном "по привычке" захожу и иногда отвечаю людям. Раньше (на другой работе) просто профессионального общения не хватало, вот тут и развлекался. А из 17к  наверное процентов 90 зашли, задали вопрос, вместо доброжелательной беседы получили по мозгам и отвалили

Comment: @avp Хорошо. Но вы лично решаете за других домашку, олимпиады?

Comment: Редко. Обычно мне это не интересно. Но я не считаю, что кто угодно в праве лишать возможности остальных сделать это

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica олимпиадные вопросы - это нормально, если они оформлены по правилам.

Comment: @avp По моим наблюдениям, наглые вопросы с домашкой все так же закрывают, только причину выбирают от балды. А хорошо оформленные вопросы с домашкой и раньше не закрывали.

Comment: Возможно, что я один из тех, кто закрывает "от балды", но если вопрос это копипаст задания или вообще скриншот/фото, то на это нельзя дать "хороший ответ". Должен быть конкретный вопрос по заданию или попытка решения в виде кода, иначе ответ будет бесполезен для сообщества, а для автора медвежьей услугой.

Comment: @RTK,  а теперь задумайтесь, может ли ответ на подобные вопросы быть полезным *отвечающему*? (представьте себе студента, который тренируется на этих вопросах). Оставьте им такие вопросы. Кстати, а описать *сообщество*, об интересах которого вы беспокоитесь, можете?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Я как раз так и закрываю :)

Comment: @avp Вопрос полезен для сообщества, ответ на который может помочь не только задающему вопрос. Студент, если хочет, пусть тренируется, никто ему не запрещает.

Comment: @RTK Абсолютно разделяю вашу позицию.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, закрывая вопросы вы как раз лишаете бедного студента возможности тренироваться. Закрывать можно лишь явный бред, спам и т.п.

Comment: @avp Зачем тренироваться оказывая медвежью услугу автору вопроса. Это на самом деле не помощь, а вред т.к он (автор вопроса с домашкой) сам не учится.

Comment: @avp Вот например: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066186). Даже если мы не вернем причину, вряд ли кто-то на такое будет отвечать.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, набраться знаний или сдать на халяву, это выбор студента. Вам-то какая разница?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а вы попробуйте не закрывать, не нравится вопрос, просто не реагируйте, пройдите мимо. А через год, скажем, посмотрим на статистику, возможно динамика вопросов и ответов изменится. / Тут еще дело в том, что [общая атмосфера](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9942/232) может от этого измениться. Не попробуем, не узнаем.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

У нас есть некоторая статистика по результатам эксперимента. В ближайшие дни мы её опубликуем и будем решать все вместе, что делать дальше.

Comment: Буду с нетерпением ждать :)

Comment: Кстати, а за что минус?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica минус не от меня.

Comment: А... Между прочим, а модераторы могут видеть кто голосует?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica нет, только сотрудники компании могут.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Имхо, раз уж написали, что эксперимент будет длиться месяц, причину стоило вернуть ровно через месяц, а уже потом анализировать результаты. На английском SO, когда [экспериментировали](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313) с количеством голосов для закрытия вопросов, так и сделали, а потом еще месяц готовили отчет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat годиться как ответ ваше сообщение. Про месяц мы и позабыли уже, например.

Answer (score 5):

Еще один вариант, если не возвращать учебные задания.

У нас есть

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, **решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям**.

Точно так же вряд ли будущим посетителям поможет решение вопроса с конкретной задачей или с очень тупым вопросом, типа, как сложить два числа (утрирую, конечно...)

Но - можно было бы дописать что-то наподобие

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, опечаткой или незнанием азов.

Такие вопросы комментировались бы - комментария обычно достаточно, чтобы ответить на такой вопрос, и закрывались бы.

Пример - не далее как сегодня вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067692/%D0%A3-clocks-per-sec-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Комментария вполне достаточно, и просто закрыть бы его...

P.S. Выскажу еще одну крамольную мысль - по-моему, ruSO давно уже ушел от декларируемой задумки "база данных вопросов и ответов". Изменить сам декларируемый принцип невозможно - но чтоб к нему вернуться, нужно очень жесткое модерирование вопросов. Конечно, imho... Да, при отсеивании таких "учебных" вопросов статистика будет не настолько впечатляющей, но, как по мне - "лучше меньше, да лучше" (с)

Comment: Предложение закрывать вопросы, притягивая причины за уши. По мне все равно что вместо `touch a1.txt`, делать вот так  `cp /dev/null a1.txt`.Я, пока отменена причина учебные задания, закрываю как "необходимо конкретизировать". Но это не правильно!

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Ну а что делать? Каждый раз просто писать текст в раздел "другое"? Наверное, так и придется поступать - один раз набросать текст, и вперед...

Comment: Вернуть причину. Если причину не вернут, а Монику вернут, то я буду Victor says Reinstate Homework Flag.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica :) Только бы не оказалось в конечном итоге *Ich bin Reinstate A Reinstate B Reinstate C Reinstate D...*

Comment: Столько не влезет ;)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Проверил - и в самом деле. Они заранее знали? :)

Comment: Хорошо подготовились ;)

Comment: На счет "как сложить два числа" категорически не согласен. Когда начинаешь изучать новую для себя технологию, такие вопросы очень полезны. В том плане, что гугл кидает такие вопросы первыми-вторыми ссылками

Comment: @AntonShchyrov И все же - есть определенный уровень у того, кто начинает изучать, и у того, кто это делать не хочет. По С++, моей основной теме, не редкость вопросы такие, что простого чтения "С++ для чайников" было бы вполне достаточно. Мы же своими ответами на такие вопросы лишаем людей мук творчества и радостей понимания/осознания... :(