# Не переведено сообщение про блокировку содержимого

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, заблокированные-сообщения

> There are disputes about this answer’s content being resolved at this time. It is not currently accepting new interactions.

[image: скриншот]

[Пример сообщения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9944/15479).

Comment: @Suvitruf, разве [meta-tag:защищённые-вопросы] не про защиту которую обычные пользователи накладывают на вопросы?

Comment: На traducir: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13865, https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13875, https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13532 . Немного промахнулся, случайно пометил 3 срочным)

Comment: @Qwertiy я уже сам запутался =/

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, а ты то сообщение в принципе разблокировать не собираешься? Я думал, это временно.

Comment: @Qwertiy навсегда заблокировал, чтоб больше не возвращаться к этому. Хотя может есть проблема, за заблокированные сообщения можно голосовать или нет? Если нельзя, то лучше снять будет чуть попозже)

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, нельзя голосовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy пускай чуток повисит тогда, пока перевод не выкатим. Потом сниму.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica А за что собственно этот ответ попал в "заблокировано"?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica для предотвращения бессмысленной войны правок.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Это не война правок. Последняя строчка содержит в себе **открытое пожелание всего плохого**, пусть это и цитата, но это все равно неприятно. На мой взгляд она не соответствует CoC:"Никаких резких замечаний или **враждебно настроенных фраз**. Какими бы ни были _ваши намерения_, подобное поведение может **негативно** отразиться на ваших коллегах." → невежливый или оскорбительный.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Но вы не вырезали только эту фразу. Вы откатили сообщение на ту ревизию, с которой не согласны автор сообщения и многие другие участники (читайте комментарии). Возвращение той ревизии, которую уже ранее откатывали является войной правок, независимо от вашего мнения о нарушении правил сообщением. Позвольте модераторам разрешить конфликт, вместо того, чтобы вмешиваться и подогревать его.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Может удалить "Всего плохого" и разблокировать ответ? Вроде обсуждение пришло к тому, что именно в части этой фразы ответ нарушает правила. К тем, кто дальше будет лезть с правками, на данном этапе можно уже будет и карательные меры применить...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight насколько я помню, сошлись на том, что это ирония и цитата. Хотя может и путаю. Можно знак © поставить напротив)

Comment: Появилось. Принимай ответ (: Лок снимаю.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, готово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13532

> Заблокируйте это сообщение, если идут споры о его содержании, которые необходимо решить.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13865

> **$lockedNoticeTitle$**. В данный момент идёт разрешение споров по поводу содержания этого ответа. Никакие действия для него недоступны.

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13875

> **$lockedNoticeTitle$**. В данный момент идёт разрешение споров по поводу содержания этого вопроса. Ответы на него не принимаются, и некоторые действия для него недоступны.