# Пополнение клуба 100k. Поздравляем KoVadim

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Заметил, что [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) перешагнул рубеж 100k.
Поздравляем со вступлением в ряды стотысячников!

Comment: Вас тоже можно поздравить с первым постом на Мете. Может быть и KoVadim последует вашему примеру.

Comment: @KoVadim Поздравляю! Просто от души!

Answer (score 15):

Поздравляю [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) с достижением **100k!**
Это очень трудный рубеж и он его достиг!
Ниже список, со ссылками на топики с поздравлениями, просто для статистики, для истории, кто, когда перешагнул этот рубеж - 100к.

Не могу найти топик с поздравлениями @VladD. Видимо это было в чате.
Буду благодарен тому, кто поможет найти ссылку с поздравлениями. Уверен, что не могло пройти  такое событие не замеченным, как первый человек, сумевший преодолеть 100к.

### ================ Клуб 100к ====================

1. [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) -  [17.09.2016](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32380198#32380198)
2. [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) - [27.02.2019](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8833/28748)
3. [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor)   - [20.03.2020](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10242/28748)
4. [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) - [13.10.2020](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10924/28748)
5. [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) - [12.11.2020](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11053/28748)
6. [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) - [16.04.2021](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11501/28748)
7. [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) - [08.10.2021](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11772/28748)

### ================ Клуб 200к ====================

1. [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) -   [30.07.2021 г.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd?tab=reputation)
2. [@Harry](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) - [21.09.2022](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12127/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc-harry-200k)

Comment: Давайте тоже достигайте! ;)

Comment: Вот ссылка с поздравлениями: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32382783#32382783

Comment: И присоединяюсь к поздравлениям @KoVadim!

Comment: @VladD Благодарю Владислав!

Comment: @Sevastopol' я то что, я не скоро, а вот `@VladD`  будем через месяц, два поздравлять с самым крутым результатом на RuSO  **+200k**

Comment: поздравляем @KoVadim! Ты сделал очень большой вклад в развитие сообщества)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям, @KoVadim :)

Comment: Предлагаю выделить таблицу участников в отдельный вопрос/ответ, где использование метки [meta-tag:вехи] будет вполне разумным. Здесь эта таблица выглядит не совсем уместной.

Comment: интересно, почему нет Harry :)

Answer (score 9):

От лица компании и русскоязычного сообщества поздравляю @KoVadim с достижением 100 000 баллов репутации. Огромное вам спасибо, что делитесь с коллегами знаниями!

Хочется отметить, что @KoVadim один из первых участников сообщества, которые вдохнули в проект жизнь на его ранней стадии развития.

Огромное вам спасибо! Без вас ничего бы не было!

Comment: Интересно, когда бы опомнилась компания, если бы не эта тема на Мете. Вообще, очень печально, что внимание компании к ruSO подсократилось в последнее время довольно существенно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ непонятно, зачем компании "опоминаться". А то что ruSO недополучает внимания, конечно жаль ..