# Поздравляем Гуру SVG Alexandr_TT с достижением 100k баллов репутации!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Наш Гуру по масштабируемой векторной графике ([SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg)) — [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) перешагнул рубеж 100k! Поздравляем!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Достижение 100 000 баллов репутации — это время, это силы, это огромный вклад в наше с вами сообщество.

[@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) многим помогал, многих научил этому интересному и, как это может только показаться на первый взгляд, простому языку разметки. От лица всех участников, кто влился в этот векторный формат благодаря или с помощью @Alexandr_TT, говорим Гуру спасибо.

Пожелаем @Alexandr_TT не останавливаться на достигнутом, оставаться на сайте и отвечать с удовольствием на вновь поступающие вопросы, тем самым продолжая помогать другим участникам сообщества.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*P.S. Саша, а от меня лично тебе простое, но большое человеческое спасибо. Искренне желаю дальнейших успехов!*

Comment: Поздравляю, так держать!

Comment: Поздравляю. *( )*

Comment: Поздрав л я ю !

Comment: [Ping 16 days](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59322009#59322009). Но, лучше поздно, чем никогда ;-) Ещё раз мои поздравления, Александр.

Comment: @UModeL, Юра, в связи с семейными обстоятельствами крайне редко последнее время бываю в интернете и только кратковременными забегами на SO, поэтому и получилось так поздно.

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо Павел, что нашёл время на оформление поздравительного топика, в условиях острого дефицита времени. Это вдвойне приятно.

Comment: @UModeL спасибо Юра, что не забыл поздравить в первый раз и поздравил во второй раз. Опять же вдвойне приятно!

Comment: @avp `@Igor`, `@MBo`  Огромное спасибо! Честно говоря не ожидал, так же как и от других ребят, кто анонимно, положительно (+) поддержал этот топик с поздравлением. Метка SVG непопулярна, мало посещаема, поэтому думал, когда была большая пауза после 100к, что я просто незнаком бОльшей части коллег на SO

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ого, это хорошее достижение, поздравляю!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Поздравляю с достигнутой важной вехой!  К ней уже ещё 1000 добавилось, осталось всего-то 99000 до очередной вехи ;)

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо Дима! Но это вряд ли :) Я уже отвечал, что если до 100к мне понадобилось идти долгих 6 лет, то следующие шесть, я явно потрачу на что ни будь другое. Отвечать конечно буду но по не многу и здесь и на EnSO. Но основная цель у меня была и есть,-  несколько другая, не эти кило, а продвижение SVG, которому сильно не повезло, но это уже другая история.. Хотя и не буду лукавить, зелёненькие цифры приносят удовлетворение, когда ответ был на уровне.

Comment: Здорово, @Alexandr_TT, мои поздравления! Вы большим и важным делом занимаетесь! Спасибо!)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Здравствуй Михаил! Вы даже не представляете, как я был благодарен вам и другим людям за поддержку в тот трудный период,  когда  в 2020 году я твёрдо решил уйти с RuSO.  Вот остался, и чтобы не говорили о SO, это на мой взгляд, самая удобная и полезная площадка. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Ура! Между прочим, это здорово, что 100k постепенно становятся обыденным явлением — значит, ruSO живет активной жизнью :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, рад, что Вы остались) Да, SO полноценных альтернатив особо и нету. Влад даже вернулся частично после длительного отсутствия. И тут двоякие ощущения. С одной стороны я очень рад возвращению, с другой... хотя лучше не будем здесь о грустном)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Надеюсь, в этом году доберусь и доведу-таки до логического конца хоть один вариант для новогоднего конкурса) Я два года подряд начинал, но из-за завалов на работе, к сожалению, никак не мог довести до ума и выложить) Может в этом году получится)

Comment: Картинки в посте не векторные (: Поздравляю!

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! могу сделать, прямо здесь и с анимацией, сниппет же есть, а надо ли? :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поздравляю! :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поздравляю!!! Ценю Ваши усилия и труд по популяризации SVG. И дело даже не в цифрах, а то как они достигались. Это генерация интересного контента, прежде всего, проактивная позиция в создании тематической базы знаний, - не просто ответы на банальные каждомелкие вопросы. Ценю Вашу готовность помогать и вникать, предлагать нестандартные подходы, вариативность решений и широкий охват знаний проблематики SVG-SMIL. Еще раз поздравляю, желаю дальнейших крутых достижений!!!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поздравляю!!!  
Огромная тебе благодарность за активное участие и помощь тут. Твой вклад огромен)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! Так держать!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, поздравляю!

Comment: @Eva Благодарю! Очень приятно. Тем более, что мы не знакомы :)

Comment: @Eva Я ошибался, вспомнил вас,, отвечал на несколько ваших вопросов и тогда удивился вашей целеустремленности разобраться до конца! И в целом общение было приятным, деловым!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! 

Comment: @HamSter Спасибо Лена! Без тебя скучно..(((  Может дождусь, когда ещё вернешься к вопросам-ответам SVG/ Они были, как правило, оч. крутые

Comment: @Alexandr_TT поздравляю с достижением :) вы реально вдыхаете жизнь в площадку и вдохновили на труд меня лично, спасибо!

Comment: @highpassion благодарю, моя основная цель была и есть, чтобы вы, как и другие ребята, кому это интересно, поняли, оценили и применяли SVG в своей работе. Тем более, что сейчас для SVG открыты все дороги.

Answer (score 23):

Огромное спасибо вам, друзья и коллеги, за праздник который вы подарили, своими отзывами о моей работе на сайте, теплыми, искренними словами поздравлений. Я очень тронут и рад, хожу который день с хорошим настроением.
Значит не зря прошли эти 7 лет в моей жизни.

### Немного о себе и о SVG.

Десять лет назад, я случайно увидел маленькую программу SVG:

```css
.container {
width:50vw;
height:50vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/ovaling.svg -->
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs id="DEF">
<linearGradient id="rhue">
    <stop offset="0" id="ro0" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset=".25" id="ro1" stop-color="blue"/>
    <stop offset=".75" id="ro2" stop-color="yellow"/>
    <stop offset="1" id="ro3" stop-color="green"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<ellipse cx="290" cy="250" rx="80" ry="80">
    <animate attributeName="fill" dur="5s" values="#ff8; #f88; #f8f; #88f; #8ff; #8f8" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</ellipse>
<g id="penta">
        <g  id="R1" transform="translate(200 250)"> 
        <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="100" ry="30" opacity=".4" fill="url(#rhue)">
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="7s" from="0" to="360" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            <animate attributeName="cx" dur="8s" values="-20; 120; -20" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
            <animate attributeName="ry" dur="3s" values="10; 60; 10" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </ellipse>
        </g>
        <use xlink:href="#R1" transform="rotate(30 300 250)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#R1" transform="rotate(60 300 250)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#R1" transform="rotate(90 300 250)"/>
        <use xlink:href="#R1" transform="rotate(120 300 250)"/>
</g>
<use xlink:href="#penta" transform="rotate(72 290 250)"/>
<use xlink:href="#penta" transform="rotate(144 290 250)"/>
<use xlink:href="#penta" transform="rotate(216 290 250)"/>
<use xlink:href="#penta" transform="rotate(288 290 250)"/>
</svg> 
</div>
```

Удивлению и восхищению не было предела. Всего 30 строчек, нет переменных, функций, циклов, подключения библиотек, как же всё это реализуется?
Захотелось разобраться, сделать что ни будь подобное и, как говорится, увяз по уши в SVG.
Сейчас я понимаю, что это элементарщина, но  любовь и восхищение к возможностям SVG от этого, со временем не уменьшилась.
Также было некоторое недоумение, почему корпорации - лидеры IT, начиная с 1999г. начали кошмарить SVG. Например такие, как Microsoft и иже с ними.

Но оказалось ничего личного, только бизнес.

- В 1998 году компаниями Microsoft, Macromedia и др. был разработан
  язык векторной разметки ***[VML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VML)***  Продукт коммерческий, с
  закрытым кодом, встроенный в IE.
- Примерно в то же время Adobe, Sun и несколько других компаний подали
  на рассмотрение документы о языке [PGML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGML). Оба языка позднее стали
  основой для ***[SVG](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG)***. Но в отличии от Microsoft эти компании выпустили   продукт с открытым кодом.

*Действия Microsoft были весьма  предсказуемы,- начиная с версии браузера IE6, был резко сокращен  уровень поддержки SVG.* До этого всё нормально работало в браузерах ослика.

- В 2011 году произошло второе рождение SVG в связи с появлением
  дисплеев повышенной четкости.

В 2001 году вышла версия 1.0, в 2011 — версия 1.1, которая остаётся актуальной до сегодняшнего дня. В настоящее время в активной разработке находится версия **[SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/)**.
Первое, что можно отметить в новой версии,- многострочный текст с переносами внутри SVG. И ещё много других революционных изменений и вкусностей.

- В 2015 году новый удар от семейства браузера Chromium, который
  объявил, что анимация SVG, ***depricate*** и её поддержка вскоре будет
  прекращена. Рекомендовали пользоваться вместо smil svg, анимацией CSS, canvas и web API.
- В 2020 году с SVG наконец сняли статус depricate, который душил его 5 лет.

Цитата из [блога chromium](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/5o0yiO440LM/m/YGEJBsjUAwAJ?pli=1)

> We value all of your feedback, and it's clear that there are use cases
> serviced by SMIL that just don’t have high-fidelity replacements yet.
> As a result, we’ve decided to suspend our intent to deprecate and take
> smaller steps toward other options

Если кратко, то не нашли полноценной замены SMIL SVG.

Почитайте, если интересно, блог разработчиков [Chromium](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/5o0yiO440LM/m/YGEJBsjUAwAJ?pli=1), как люди  боролись за SMIL SVG.

В 2021 году IE11 умер, браузер Edge Microsoft перешел на движок ***[blink](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA))***, что означает полную поддержку SMIL SVG.

Вот ***[так](https://caniuse.com/?search=smil)***, выглядит теперь в конце 2021 года, поддержка smil браузерами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суммарный процент поддержки всеми браузерами составляет ***97%*** и выше.

Ура, коллеги! SVG выжил, несмотря на все попытки его проигнорировать или задушить.  Можно смело брать его на вооружение. Изображения на сайте должны быть векторными, для этого и был создан **S**calable **V**ector **G**raphics

### О Stackoverflow

Чтобы не говорили о RuSO, на мой взгляд, это лучшая площадка рунета для программистов.
Мы ругаем RuSO, сродни, как родители ругают любимое дитя, потому что, хотим, чтобы оно было лучше.
Не любили бы, ничего бы не говорили, а просто ушли.
Я благодарен сайту, за то, что нашел здесь единомышленников и друзей, с которыми могу обмениваться идеями и  знаниями.

Answer (score 10):

Хотел бы тоже сказать несколько слов об «имениннике».

SVG — точно не моя область, но я время от времени заглядываю и туда, и мне всегда нравились ответы Александра.

В них есть многое, к чему, мне кажется, стоит стремиться всем нам: и детальное объяснение, и много дополнительной информации. У нас давно был нерешённый вопрос о том, как же следует отвечать на узкоспециальные вопросы, и Александр показывает нам примеры того, как же нужно: прочитав ответ, можно почерпнуть для себя куда больше чем просто информация в тесных рамках заданного вопроса. И это замечательно, потому что только так и можно распространять знания.

А ещё отмечу то, чем многие пренебрегают: у ответов Александра всегда есть замечательная эстетическая составляющая. На получающееся кино просто здорово смотреть, да и фоновая музыка всегда отлично подобрана и вызывает улыбку.

Ну и отдельно впечатляет такое количество отличных ответов по достаточно редкой метке SVG, где, казалось бы, особенно нечего сказать. А вот видите, есть.

Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям, и спасибо за ваш труд и небезразличие.

Comment: Благодарю! Для меня было очень важно и ценно услышать ваше мнение. Ваши слова вдохновляют и дают дополнительные, новые силы.

Answer (score 5):

Хотел бы от себя поздравить **Alexandr_TT** с этим достижением.

Его переведённые ответы с **SO** по SVG и вопросы-конкурсы проявили у меня интерес в работе с SVG (думаю я не один такой).

Так же, пользуясь моментом, хочу поблагодарить за развитие тега `svg` на **ruSO** и за представленную помощь мне не только по SVG, но и другим вопросам.

Спасибо и ещё раз поздравляю

Comment: Спасибо Денис! Мне всегда было интересно и приятно работать с тобой. Ты очень быстро растешь в программировании, схватываешь всё на лету. Пожелаю и тебе, успехов и везения во всех делах и начинаниях!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо :)

Answer (score 5):

Поздравляю с достижением такого значимого рубежа! Большое спасибо за ваши вопросы и ответы! Отдельная благодарность за активность на Мете и ассоциации вопросов между сайтами! Без вас русскоязычное SVG сообщество не было бы таким крутым :)

Comment: Благодарю за добрые слова. Кстати об ассоциациях, новый пакет вопросов готов и ждёт отправки на EnSO. И вам благодарность за поддержку от всех ребят, кто занимается этим.