# Поздравляем Harry - 200k

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Ответ за ответом - и Harry вступил в виртуальный клуб 200k.
Это весьма солидно даже по меркам "большого" SO, а уж если отнормировать на аудиторию...
Поздравляем!

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! :-) 200 тысяч - это не шутки. И что не менее важно - Harry продолжает быть активным участником сообщества  (я бы даже сказал самым активным судя по рейтингу за год) Всех самых наилучших пожеланий и мирного неба над головой!

Comment: @Harry Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям!

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, но по-хорошему после 100 очередной юбилей — 250 :) Надо немного подождать...

Comment: Поздравляю!!!!!!!!

Comment: Поздравляю и желаю новых успехов!

Comment: @МихаилРебров поздравляю!!!

Comment: Этот пост должен набрать 200 плюсов. Не ленитесь, голосуйте.

Comment: Мне бы так не лениться : )

Comment: Господин @Harry очень часто помогал мне с моими порой нелепыми вопросами по программированию), давал бесценные советы. Даже не знаю, что бы Я и многие другие без него делали. Незаменимый и очень умный человек!!!

Comment: Поздравляю с юбилеем, желаю поскорее добраться до 250К!

Comment: @Harry, присоединяюсь к поздравлениям!

Comment: Мои поздравления =) Надеюсь тоже когда ни будь догоню

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что веха была и прошла, обсуждений более не требует )

Answer (score 11):

Поздавляем @Harry, желаем ему еще не раз побить рекорды на SO, отвечайте так же активно, помогайте, радуйтесь жизни! Дарим вам котенка!!![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 9):

Поздравляю, спасибо за ваши ответы!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Кроме всего прочего Harry еще и является очень адекватным, дружелюбным, приятным человеком, всегда готовым помогать, поддерживать, высказать свое бескорыстное мнение... Так что, с огромным удовольствием присоединяюсь к поздравлениям и хочу добавить  поздравления сайту и его пользователей по поводу его участия, которая, надеюсь, будет еще долгой.

Answer (score 2):

Грац @Harry! Много где вижу твои ответы и они правда очень помогают!